# How to do validation with mat-checkbox?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material2

I would like to know how to check if the checkbox was selected, if it was not selected, an error message will appear for the user.
I managed to put the error message but not to able to use it along with the rest of the form.
can you help me?
Here's what I have to do.

```
<mat-checkbox class="hcs-full-width" [formControl]="termsFormControl"> Aceite os termos de uso

</mat-checkbox>
<mat-error *ngIf="termsFormControl.hasError('required')">
    Termo é
    <strong>requirido</strong>
</mat-error>
```

.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  private subscription: Subscription;
  uri: string;
  ssid: string;
  sessiondId: string;
  ip: string;
  mac: string;
  ufi: string;
  mgmtBaseUrl: string;
  clientRedirectUrl: string;
  req: string;
  userName: string;
  hmac: string;

  name: string;
  email: string;

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams
      .filter(params => params.mac)
      .subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params);

        this.ssid = params.ssid;
        this.sessiondId = params.sessionId;
        this.ip = params.ip;
        this.mac = params.mac;
        this.ufi = params.ufi;
        this.mgmtBaseUrl = params.mgmtBaseUrl;
        this.clientRedirectUrl = params.clientRedirectUrl;
        this.req = params.req;
        this.hmac = params.hmac;
      });
      console.log("LOGAR: " + this.nameFormControl.valid);
    console.log("LOGAR: " + this.termsFormControl.valid);
  }

  Logar() {
    if (this.nameFormControl.valid && this.emailFormControl.valid && this.termsFormControl.valid) {
      this.userName = this.name + ";" + this.email;
      this.uri = "#" + this.ssid + "&sessionId=" + this.sessiondId + "&ip=" + this.ip + "&mac=" + this.mac + "&ufi=" + this.ufi + "&mgmtBaseUrl=" + this.mgmtBaseUrl + "&clientRedirectUrl=" + this.clientRedirectUrl + "&req=" + this.req + "&username=" + this.userName + "&hmac=" + this.hmac;
      // console.log("LOGAR: " + this.nameFormControl.valid);
      this.document.location.href = this.uri;
    }
    console.log("LOGAR: " + this.nameFormControl.valid);
    console.log("LOGAR: " + this.termsFormControl.valid);
  };

  emailFormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.email,
  ]);

  nameFormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
  ]);

  termsFormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
  ]);

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkbox doesn't work like that, you have to implement custom validator and assign to your `termsFormControl`. In your case it will be:

```
termsFormControl = new FormControl('', [(control) => {    
    return !control.value ? { 'required': true } : null;
  }]
);
```

Here custom validator explicitly checking value of control and if is false it will set `required` error to be `true`. On that way you can set state to your form and be able to consume powerful features.

Please see following [issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8662) on GitHub for more explanation why you have to implement custom validation.

**EDITED 1**

To show error message when button is clicked you can set condition to rise error when checkbox isinvalid and dirty:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="termsFormControl.invalid && termsFormControl.dirty">
        Termo é <strong>requirido</strong>
</mat-error>
```

Then on button click you can set checkbox to be dirty (I don't see your entire code but it should be something like this):

```
onSubmit() {
  this.form.get('termsFormControl ').markAsDirty();
}
```

**EDITED 2**

Based on @Julida suggestion built in [validator](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#requiredTrue) `Validators.requiredTrue` is available for checkbox elements. It validate does checkbox is checked or unchecked. It marks control invalid if is unchecked.

Comment: kat1330 thanks for replying, but I would like to know how to make the error message appear only when the user clicks the button and has not selected the checkbox.

Comment: @Mark I updated answer. Basically I extended case in HTML to display message if is control invalid and dirty. Then on button click I am marking control to be dirty.

Comment: @kat1330 Why not using the build-in validator "requiredTrue"? `termsFormControl = new FormControl(false, Validators.requiredTrue)`

Answer (score 9):

Use build-in validator: Validators.requiredTrue

Answer (score 1):

`Required` in this case won't work because technically speaking `false` is a value. So, you must use `RequiredTrue`, e.g.:

```
termsFormControl = new FormControl(false, [Validators.requiredTrue]);
```

Nonetheless, if you need to check whether this option has been checked, lets say to display a message, you must verify for the error of `required`:

```
  get acceptTermsErrorMessage() {
    if (this.form.hasError('required', 'termsFormControl')) {
      return "You must accept the terms and conditions in order to continue;
    }

    return '';
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<mat-checkbox 
 (change)="todoItemSelectionToggle($event)">{{node.item}}</mat-checkbox>


        In .ts file if event.checked is true checkbox is selected else viceversa


         todoItemSelectionToggle(event)
         {
         console.log = event.checked;
         }
```